# selenium Timed out waiting for page load with proxys

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Im using proxys to connect to a website using selenium and test a few things, the issue is some of the proxys are incredibly slow and it makes things really inefficient, but the other issue is I can't catch the error and carry on no matter what I do.. Tried all sorts of suggestions from other stack posts but to no avail.

```
    org.openqa.selenium.Proxy proxy = new org.openqa.selenium.Proxy();
    proxy.setHttpProxy(ip+":"+port);
    proxy.setSslProxy(ip+":"+port);
    proxy.setFtpProxy(ip+":"+port);


    DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    dc.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(dc);

            try {


                driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
                driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 

                driver.navigate().to("http://foo.bar");  


            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                driver.quit();
                driver = null;
                break;
            }
```

I set the timeout to 15 seconds because it has to navigate through a few pages and some of the proxys take 30-40 seconds just to load a page so it would take considerably longer, is there actually a way to catch the error

```
Timed out waiting for page load
```

My other question is, would it be easier to use an alternative to selenium ? up to now Iv'e had a few issues with selenium that seem to have been around for a while judging by others peoples posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scriptss,

It looks to me like you have need of ExplicitWaits to validate your navigation.  Rather than using the implicit configuration in the driver the ExplicitWaits allow for a more flexible solution, depending on your environment.  In my experience, the WebDriverWait class, in combination with the ExpectedConditions have solved most of my problems.  I have not yet gotten into Proxy support for the Drivers, but it seems consistent with information I've acquired to this point.

That being said, I'm not entirely certain why you're not seeing an exception being thrown.  When I'm having similar issues I will wrap my WebDriver in an EventFiringWebDriver and see if the onException message of the WebDriverEventListener gets hit in those cases.

In the sample below, you will need to fill out the constants for your Proxy IP and Port, as well as the actual URL you want to go to. In the createParameters method, you will also need to update the Strings for title and partial url to fit your use case.

Built with Java 8 and Selenium v 2.47.2

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.logging.Level;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.events.AbstractWebDriverEventListener;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class ExplicitWaitNavigationTest {
    /** IP configuration for the proxy.*/
    private static final String PROXY_IP = "";
    /** Port configuration for the proxy.*/
    private static final int PROXY_PORT = 8080;
   
    /** The url the test will navigate to.*/
    private static final String TEST_URL = "http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/dropdown";
    /** Maximum time to wait for a page to load.*/
    private static final int PAGE_LOAD_SECONDS = 15;
    /** Maximum time to wait for javascript to complete.*/
    private static final int SCRIPT_LOAD_SECONDS = 15;
    
    /** ExpectedCondition used to validate the navigation state.*/
    private ExpectedCondition<Boolean> navTestCondition;
    /** The URL to be tested in this instance.*/
    private String url;
    /** WebDriver reference used for testing navigation through proxy.*/
    private WebDriver webDriver;
    
    /**
     * Assembles the Constructor arguments for testing.
     * Due to test parameterization, each pair is run as a separate test.
     * @return Object array of test parameters.
     */
    @Parameters
    public static Object[] createParameters() {
        List<Object[]> params = Lists.newArrayList();
        String url = TEST_URL;
        
        //Test that url exactly matches
        ExpectedCondition<Boolean> test = ExpectedConditions.urlToBe(url);
        params.add(new Object[]{test, url});
        
        //Test if the url matches a regex?
        test = ExpectedConditions.urlMatches(url); //regex match? I'm not great with regex
        params.add(new Object[]{test, url});
        
        //Test if the url contains the base site, or other fragment information
        test = ExpectedConditions.urlContains("dropdown");
        params.add(new Object[]{test, url});
        
        // Test if the page title exactly matches expectation.
        test = ExpectedConditions.titleIs("The Internet");
        params.add(new Object[]{test, url});
        
        //Test if the page title somewhat matches expectation
        test = ExpectedConditions.titleContains("Internet");
        params.add(new Object[]{test, url});
        
        
        return params.toArray(new Object[]{});        
    }
    
    /**
     * Turns off noisy logging that is on by default in the Selenium structure.
     */
    @BeforeClass
    public static void disableHttpUnitOutput() {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(Level.OFF);
        System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.Log", "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.NoOpLog");
    }
    
    /**
     * Constructor.
     * @param waitCondition Expected condition to validate in this effort.
     * @param url URL being navigated to.
     */
    public ExplicitWaitNavigationTest(ExpectedCondition<Boolean> waitCondition, String url) {
        this.navTestCondition = waitCondition;
        this.url = url;
    }
    
    /**
     * Configures the Driver for this test instance.
     */
    @Before
    public void setupDriver() {
        org.openqa.selenium.Proxy proxy = new org.openqa.selenium.Proxy();
        String proxyConfig = PROXY_IP + ":" + PROXY_PORT;
        proxy.setHttpProxy(proxyConfig);
        proxy.setSslProxy(proxyConfig);
        proxy.setFtpProxy(proxyConfig);


        DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        dc.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);

        FirefoxDriver ffd = new FirefoxDriver(dc);
        ffd.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(PAGE_LOAD_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
        ffd.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(SCRIPT_LOAD_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
    
        //XXX EventFiringWebDriver decoration
        EventFiringWebDriver efwd = new EventFiringWebDriver(ffd);
        efwd.register(new AbstractWebDriverEventListener() {            
            @Override
            public void onException(Throwable throwable, WebDriver driver) {
                System.out.println("Exception thrown from within the EventFiringWebDriver");
                throwable.printStackTrace();
            }            
            @Override
            public void beforeNavigateTo(String url, WebDriver driver) {
                System.out.println("Before NavigateTo :: " + url);
            }            
            @Override
            public void afterNavigateTo(String url, WebDriver driver) {
                System.out.println("After NavigateTo :: " + url);
            }
            
        });  
        
        webDriver = efwd;
        
    }
    
    /**
     * Test instance which attempts to navigate to the configured url and establishes an ExplicitWait to confirm
     * navigation before continuing with the test event.
     */
    @Test
    public void testPageLoadFeedback() {
        webDriver.navigate().to(url);
        /*
         * FIXME: How long are you actually willing to wait.
         * 
         * It's my understanding that if the wait value is less than the implicit wait, then the looping capabilities of
         * the ExplicitWait are never really leveraged.
         * 
         * Note that the time value is the maximum time to wait. If the condition validates before the time specified
         * then the process will continue.
         */
        
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, PAGE_LOAD_SECONDS * 2);
        wait.pollingEvery(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        wait.until(navTestCondition);
        // If we get to this line then the test passed and we should be on the page.
        System.out.println("Navigation Succeeded!");
    }    
    
    /**
     * Cleanup method to close any browsers used by the test session.
     */
    @After
    public void cleanupTest() {
        //XXX:  To leave the browser open, comment out the @After of this method.
        for (String handle : webDriver.getWindowHandles()) {
            webDriver.switchTo().window(handle);
            webDriver.close();
        }
    }
    
}
```

Good luck, I hope this helps.